# $2^m+3^n+5^p+7^q+11^r=s!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve on$ \,\,\Bbb N$ :

#### $$ 2^m+3^n+5^p+7^q+11^r=s!$$

In my attempt to solve this equation. I found $(0,1,0,0,0,3)$ and $(2,0,0,,1,1,4)$ and some more solutions. I tried to reduce it using congruent, I failed.Question proposed by Jalil Hajimir.
$$\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$$

---

**Edit:** I tried $\mod 7$ and also $\mod 2\times3\times5\times7\times11$, I know it does not have any solution beyond $s=11$ *" as a friend mentioned".*

Comment: I am curious: Who is Jalil Hajimir and where are those problems proposed?

Comment: Most of themsproposed on RMM. He i my mentor.

Comment: Isn't $\;\Bbb N^*=\{1,2,3,...\}\;$ ? Because if it so then none of your finding is acceptable.

Comment: What is RMM? Is it a public forum?

Comment: We use that as 0,1,2,3...

Comment: Come on, don't make me pulling worms out of your nose. – What is the name of the magazine? In which issue is the problem published? Is it publicly available?

Comment: Mr. Hajimir is a great mathematician and also a math olmpiad coach from Iran.

Comment: Listen! This is not a right way to ask a question.

Comment: https://www.ssmrmh.ro

Comment: Looking at your earlier linked problem with only $3,4,5$ I would look at congruences modulo $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11=2320$. This is going to be tedious, but it will give you a lot of restrictions on $m,n,p,q,r$. Maybe it is sufficient to prove that there are no solutions beyond $s=11$.

Comment: i agree there are no solution beyond 11

Comment: Since such a *great mathematician* is your mentor , we expect you to put more efforts in your question . They are always like *'I tried to solve this .... but I can't solve it'* . Try to show your work to the community to get helped better.

Comment: I am a grade 11 student in Ontario and I try my best before I ask. I only ask questoins that  I have dffiiculty with. I do not think my showing my work is helping when I can not get the answer. One more thing The way you and Martin talking is not friendly, I hope I am not right about that.

Comment: No trying to be disrespectful , but if you take a look at the some of the questions on the site, you will realize that most of the time the O.P is usually solving correctly and just makes one small mistake and thinks that he can't solve it . By posting your work , we can better identity the problem.

Comment: I think you meant $(1,0,0,0,0,3)$, not $(0,1,0,0,0,3)$: $2^1+3^0+5^0+7^0+11^0=2+1+1+1+1=6=3!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall s>2,~2^m+5^p+7^q+11^r\equiv 0\pmod 3\implies 2^m+2^p+2^r+1\equiv 0\pmod 3$$ implying 1 or all of $m,p,r$ are odd.

If $$m\neq 1$$:

$$\forall s>3,~3^n+5^p+7^q+11^r\equiv 0\pmod 4\implies 3^n+3^q+3^r+1\equiv 0\bmod 4$$ implying 1 or all of $n,q,r$ are odd.

$$\forall s>4,~2^m+3^m+7^q+11^r\equiv 0\pmod 5\implies 2^m+(-2)^n+2^q+1\equiv 0\bmod 5 $$ in the case that $n$ is even, we get that either 2 give back additive inverses, leading to the other being 2 mod 4, or we have two of $m,n,q$ being equal mod 4, forcing the other exponent into a certain value based on the value,1,2,3,4 mod 5 the others land on.

Most of this is simply using $s!\equiv 0\pmod s$ casting out constants that appear, and attempting to equate the rest. it's a fairly general method.